# why event callback not a function will running immediately in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, callback

1. `setTimeout(console.log("test"),1000);`
2. `setTimeout(function(){console.log("test");},1000);`

The first code will be executed immediately while the second will wait 1s after the execution.In my opinion , they are asynchronous function should be triggered in the event after execution.so why they work different? last,my english is not very will ,Thanks for patiently reading！

Comment: asynchronous function?

Comment: RTFM ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Yuck, code evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `console.log()` immediately and providing the result of that to `setTimeout` (which is invalid anyway).

It could however be written as:

```
setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, 'test'), 1000);
```

Comment: will it not wait for a second before executing `console.log` statement?

Comment: No, it waits a second before attempting to call the function provided as the first argument of `setTimeout`. In this case I believe `undefined` is the value provided for the first argument, the result of *immediately calling `console.log()`*.

Comment: @techie_28 No, it won't. Parameters passed to functions are evaluated at the point the function is called before it's invoked. `console.log()` is an expression, which is evaluated, and then the result (undefined) is then passed to `setTimeout` as the value for the parameter.

Comment: from the manual `window.setTimeout(code, [delay])` is this not this case?

Comment: @techie_28 - When you say "the manual" you seem to be quoting the MDN page? Read *the whole thing*. You can either pass a *string* of code to be eval'ed (which they recommend against), or pass a function *reference*.

Comment: @nnnnnn Im just little confused on why `console.log` statement wont be treated as code here?Please explain.

Comment: @techie_28 - Where the doco you referred to said `code` it was talking about a *string* that contains code. Think about a generic example: if you say `a(b())` then `b()` is called first and its result passed to `a()`. It's the same with the code in the question, except `a()` is `setTimeout()` and `b()` is `console.log()`. As compared to `a("b()")`, where `a()` is called with a string.